# Google BigTable access error

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I need to read from BigTable in my java application.  I am using the google-cloud-bigtable hbase client.  I have added the dependency to my pom file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
   <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.x</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-google-common-protos</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And attempt to create a connection:

```
Connection connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(projectID, instanceID));
```

When I run the code I receive the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:128)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:113)
```

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513367/could-not-find-an-appropriate-constructor-for-com-google-cloud-bigtable-hbase1-x) suggests that this can be solved by setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.  I have set this up as an environment variable on systen and as a maven setting on the Eclipse run configuration but still receive the same error.

Thanks for looking.

**UPDATE**

Longer stack trace as requested.  Please don't be mislead by mentions of dataflow, this is attempting to access BigTable in the standard manner rather than as part of a dataflow pipeline.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an appropriate constructor for com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:128)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:113)
at com.ps.pt.BinReader.getBinDetails(BinReader.java:27)
at dataflows.MessageTypesTests.testBinReader(MessageTypesTests.java:136)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableConfiguration.connect(BigtableConfiguration.java:125)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.cloud.bigtable.config.BigtableOptions$Builder.setAdminHost(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/cloud/bigtable/config/BigtableOptions$Builder;
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableOptionsFactory.fromConfiguration(BigtableOptionsFactory.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:111)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_x.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:49)
... 31 more
```

Comment: Do you have more of the stacktrace?  The stacktrace you gave was a good start, but not enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Similar issue was discussed previously in the official GitHub issue tracker([link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1273)). Could you try create class manually as described there? It might be fruitful to raise this issue over there.

Answer (score 2):

The most relevant part of the stack trace is here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.cloud.bigtable.config.BigtableOptions$Builder.setAdminHost(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/cloud/bigtable/config/BigtableOptions$Builder;
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableOptionsFactory.fromConfiguration(BigtableOptionsFactory.java:301)
```

From these lines, we can see that the `BigtableOptionsFactory`, which is declared in the bigtable-hbase jar, is trying to call `BigtableOptions.setAdminHost`, which is declared in bigtable-client-core. Given the `NoSuchMethodError`, that means that when we compiled the bigtable-hbase jar at 1.3.0, the `BigtableOptions.setAdminHost` method was available in the bigtable-client-core 1.3.0 jar. It is therefore very likely that your versions of the two jars don't match. In fact, setAdminHost was added as a method in https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/commit/6c0756973b12e5fd2a9546a49342bb7e96ae28b3, which was merged in version 1.1.0, so your bigtable-client-core is probably a version from before that. Can you verify that?